# Change server location for HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/big-data/how-to-install-hadoop-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan.html, but getting a strange error when trying to run the line

```
sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

It doesn't raise any complaints when I run the script, but the namenode is not actually started. When I went to inspect the logs, I saw this error:

```
2020-01-30 13:30:52,700 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer.start() threw a non Bind IOException
java.net.BindException: Port in use: censoredsite.com:0
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:995)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeHttpServer.start(NameNodeHttpServer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:877)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1671)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:990)
```

Which was preceded by this line earlier:

```
2020-01-30 13:30:52,359 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil: Starting Web-server for hdfs at: http://censoredsite.com/archive:50070
```

It seems that somehow the web-server for HDFS has been set to something that it shouldn't be, I searched around online but I couldn't find what this value should properly be (I assume localhost?) OR how to actually change it in the config files.

The other interesting thing is that this "censoredsite" is actually a uh... lewd site I used to visit a few years ago. I have absolutely no idea how it managed to get into my HDFS configuration details, pretty worrying that it somehow worked its way into my computer. Does anyone now how to explicitly change the location of org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it ended up in your /etc/hosts file as a site mapping...

The way to change the address, though, is in the hdfs-site.xml

`dfs.namenode.http-address`

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Alternatively, install Hadoop in a VM or download the Cloudera quickstart ones, where it's all pre-configured